# Left padding a string to sort accordingly

Tags: powershell, exchange-server-2010

I have to get the database with the max space free in a exchange 2010 however as this gonna be launched from a pipeline in c#, I'm trying to sort the results and then pick the first row.

If I try using the field **AvailableNewMailboxSpace**, it is sorted using the string values instead the double values:

```
 Get-MailboxDatabase  -Status | Select Name,AvailableNewMailboxSpace | Sort-Object DatabaseSize

Name           AvailableNewMailboxSpace    
----           ------------------------    
DBMB03         123.1 MB (129,073,152 bytes)
DBMB04         114.1 MB (119,635,968 bytes)
DBMB02         115.6 MB (121,176,064 bytes)
DBMB10         224.4 MB (235,307,008 bytes)
DBMB01         81.47 MB (85,426,176 bytes)
```

I guess I must left pad zeros in the string to get the right order but I don't know how.

I have to achieve it in a single line because this gonna be launched using a pipeline command in c#.

This is my attempt:

```
Get-MailboxDatabase  -Status |`
Sort (("0" * (10 - {$_.AvailableNewMailboxSpace.Substring(0, $_.AvailableNewMailboxSpace.IndexOf("MB") - 1)}.length)) + `
{$_.AvailableNewMailboxSpace.Substring(0, $_.AvailableNewMailboxSpace.IndexOf("MB") - 1)}) | Select Name,AvailableNewMailboxSpace
```

Comment: I choose the Shay recommendation because it's the simplest one:                  Get-MailboxDatabase -Status | Select Name,AvailableNewMailboxSpace | Sort-Object {[double]$_.AvailableNewMailboxSpace.Split()[0]}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way would be to use the native methods: ToKB(),ToMB(),ToGB() etc:

```
 Get-MailboxDatabase -Status | Select Name,@{n='AvailableNewMailboxSpaceMB';e={$_.AvailableNewMailboxSpace.Value.ToMB()} | Sort-Object DatabaseSize
```

or

```
 Get-MailboxDatabase -Status | Select Name,AvailableNewMailboxSpace | Sort-Object {$_.AvailableNewMailboxSpace.Value.ToMB()}
```

If for some reason you can't do that then do string manipulation:

```
 Get-MailboxDatabase -Status | Select Name,AvailableNewMailboxSpace | Sort-Object {[double]$_.AvailableNewMailboxSpace.Split()[0]}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
| sort { [decimal]($_.AvailableNewMailboxSpace -replace "MB (\(.+\))") }
```

The scriptblock `{}` make sort evaluating only the value before MB as `decimal`.

For a more accurate sorting based on bytes value you can try this:

```
| sort { [int]($_.AvailableNewMailboxSpace -replace ".+\((.+)b.+", '$1') }
```

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you cast while sorting? So in your pipeline you'd get something like

```
... blah ... | Sort-Object { $_.AvailableNewMailboxSpace -as [int] }
```

Cannot test that because I don't have snapins for Exchange, but this is just to give you one track.

Comment: it does not sort properly, it keeps sorting as if not instruction is applied. Thanks,